# React native with expo TypeError: global.__reanimatedWorkletInit is not a function. (In 'global.__reanimatedWorkletInit(_f)',

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

After upgrading expo to SDK 45 I'm getting this error.
I'm using "react-native-reanimated-carousel"
Is anyone else getting those errors???

TypeError: global.__reanimatedWorkletInit is not a function. (In 'global.__reanimatedWorkletInit(_f)', 'global.__reanimatedWorkletInit' is undefined)
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:4 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:203:6 in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.12.246:19000/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:585435:3 in global code

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called.
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:4 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError

Versions

react: v17.0.2
react-native: v0.68.2
react-native-reanimated: v~2.8.0
react-native-reanimated-carousel: v^2.6.0
react-native-gesture-handler: v~2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Adding in the `"@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from"` plugin to my babel.config.js fixed this for me.

I found this solution here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated/#web-support

---

I ran into this issue also with an Expo 44 -> 45 upgrade.
I'm glad I ran across someone having this same issue :)